# Why ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET Toolkit is made as open source?

Tags: open-source-gis, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Is there any specific reason for making only **ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET Toolkit** an open source project where as the actual **ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET** is proprietary?

Though this question sounds weird, I just want to understand whether to deliver more useful features based on the community feedback?

Comment: I know this sounds like nit-picking - but this is a common mistake. "open source" and "commercial" are not mutually exclusive. Many Open Source packages are commercial. The comparison should be "open source" vs "proprietary software".

Comment: @Ragi Yaser Burhum: Thanks for the tip. It has made me realize my false understanding on them till now. But I could still see the inappropriate use of Open source and Commercial. This [Software Commercialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_and_closed-source_software#Commercialization) Wikipedia article would give more insight.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just saw a session on this at the Esri Dev Summit last week.  The [toolkit-dotnet](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-toolkit-dotnet) is open source because Esri wants this toolkit to be a place where helper controls and utilities can be improved by the user community. Essentially, I think they want some feedback and want to get a better understanding of what people want out of a toolkit for the .NET Runtime SDK.

From what I understood from the presenter is that Esri wants people to make requests for new controls/utilities based on their own use cases by logging issues or making pull requests.  They also want the user community to improve any controls they push to the repo. Any changes get reviewed by the team and if they think they are good improvements, they'll be merged with the main branch.

So yes, I think the goal is that they want to include more useful features that align with use cases.